# Extra characters in XSLT output

Tags: xslt

I'm delving into XML and XSLT and am trying to generate a basic, tabular web page.  The basic layout of the table seems to be ok, but I'm getting a column of " characters before I get my two-column table (which itself is in the second column of the web page).  This is shown below:

[image]

There are exactly the number of " characters as there are elements of the XML file this is built from.  The code that I think is causing the problem is listed below:

```
      <tbody>
        <xsl:for-each select="command">
          <tr>
            <td width="50%">
              <xsl:value-of select="description"/>
            </td>"
            <td width="50%">
              <xsl:value-of select="TLC"/>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </xsl:for-each>
      </tbody>
```

Is the character being generated in each `xsl:for-each select`? In the event that the above snippet of code looks good, I'll include the entirety of the XSLT file below.  Feel free to let me know how dumpy my stuff looks, as I'm coming from a firmware and .NET background.

Thanks.

**EDIT**: Removed the full body of code since the answer, so obvious that I should smack myself, doesn't involve it.

Comment: "Is the character being generated in each xsl:for-each select?" - yes. And what is the question?

Comment: I appreciate everyone's patience...  I deserved to be whipped for missing that.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is right here:

```
</td>"
<td width="50%">
```

You're inserting a `"` which is not inside a cell, thus the browser displays it outside...

Answer (score 2):

> The code that I think is causing the
>   problem is listed below:
>
> ```
>   <tbody> 
>     <xsl:for-each select="command"> 
>       <tr> 
>         <td width="50%"> 
>           <xsl:value-of select="description"/> 
>         </td>" 
>         <td width="50%"> 
>           <xsl:value-of select="TLC"/> 
>         </td> 
>       </tr> 
>     </xsl:for-each> 
>   </tbody>
> ```

**This is obvious**: Just remove the `"` character in the 6th line of the above code snippet.